# raspberry pi 4b, python, opencv, When trying to process video frames the instructions do not run sequentially

Tags: python, opencv

I have a problem when executing the programme below, So basically what's happening is when I execute the programme I expect it to open the camera (logitec usb camera) capture a frame, process it, recognize the object, send a command to Arduino to rotate a motor to flip the object to fall and liberate the space for another object, wait for half a second then repeat the process all over again until the condition is satisfied. But what happens is when I execute the programme, at first it detects nothing (which is good because there's actually nothing)
then when I introduce an object it keeps detecting nothing for about 5-8 frames then it detects the object and it keeps detecting it even when I remove it or gets dropped for about 5-8 frames (which causes the platform to rotate about 5-8 times) and so on. as I said, I need to capture a frame process it and recognize the object, drop it with the motor then and until then repeat the process.

That's the code I'm working on:

```py
def predict(self):
        print('start predicting : ' + str(self.started))
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640)
        cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
        while self.started is True and self.token is not None:
            print("predicting")
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                return
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            cv2_im = frame.copy()
            cv2_im = cv2.resize(cv2_im, (self.height, self.width))
            img_array = np.asarray(cv2_im * 1. / 255, dtype='float32')
            predictions = self.lite_model(img_array[None, ...])[0] # Prediction process, it takes 1.3-1.7 sec
            y_lite = np.argmax(predictions)
            self.save_operation(y_lite) # this is a thread
            class_name = self.getClass(y_lite)
            print("class_name = "+class_name)
            if class_name == "object1":
                self.serial.write(b'r')
                print("turn right")
                sleep(.8)
            elif class_name == "object2":
                self.serial.write(b'l')
                print("turn left")
                sleep(.8)
            self.save_img(frame, class_name) # this is a thread

        cap.release()
```

I managed to make it work by turning on and off the camera for each frame but that resulted in another problem (camera start timeout) which i solved by adding a sleep(1.2) to let the camera takes it's time to be shutdown, but this is not good as it takes more time then it should to complete the process and I need to be fast.

```py
def predict(self):
        print('start predicting : ' + str(self.started))
        
        while self.started is True and self.token is not None:
            print("predicting")
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Turn on the camera
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640)
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
            ret, frame = cap.read() # read a frame
            if not ret:
                return
            cap.release() # Release Camera resources
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            cv2_im = frame.copy()
            cv2_im = cv2.resize(cv2_im, (self.height, self.width))
            img_array = np.asarray(cv2_im * 1. / 255, dtype='float32')
            predictions = self.lite_model(img_array[None, ...])[0] # Prediction process, it takes 1.3-1.7 sec
            y_lite = np.argmax(predictions)
            self.save_operation(y_lite) # this is a thread
            class_name = self.getClass(y_lite)
            print("class_name = "+class_name)
            if class_name == "object1":
                self.serial.write(b'r')
                print("turn right")
            elif class_name == "object2":
                self.serial.write(b'l')
                print("turn left")
            self.save_img(frame, class_name) # this is a thread
            sleep(1.2) # For the camera to shutdown properly
```

The whole process now takes about 3 sec. but if you miss putting the object at the right time it could take up to 5 sec, but I'm hoping I could get it to take less than 2 sec.

Capture a frame -> process it (1.3-1.7 sec) -> drop it (half a sec)-> capture a frame->...

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you read the Question? if you don't have an answer don't comment.

Comment: I read the description of the problem, and a description of your workaround, but I do not see a specific question ... different people may ask different questions, such as `how to debug?`, `where are the log files?`, `is this a known issue?`

Comment: hhh I'm sorry if I haven't said it explicitly, but from you reading the problem description and the workaround do you have any idea how to overcome the issue of having multiple frames taken out before start processing them? meaning, what can be done to make the programme runs as follows:  Capture a frame -> process it (1.3-1.7 sec) -> drop it (half a sec)-> capture a frame->...